# Array of dynamic texboxes

Tags: arrays, dynamic, excel, textbox, vba

In the form, everytime I click te button, a new textbox has to appear. 
I want to make an Array with all of these textboxes.
The problem is, that al these textboxes have a dynamic name.
How do I have to put them in the Array?
Here's my code:

```
Set nieuwtxtingredient = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", "Ingredient", True)
With nieuwtxtingredient
.Width = Me.txtIngredient0.Width
.Height = Me.txtIngredient0.Height
.Left = Me.txtIngredient0.Left
.Top = Me.txtIngredient0.Top + 30 * aantalBoxes
.Name = "txtIngredient" + CStr(aantalBoxes)
End With

Dim naam As String
Dim ingredientArray() As String

ReDim ingredientArray(1 To aantalBoxes)
ingredientArray(aantalBoxes) = **Me.txtIngredient0.Value**
```

Comment: Why are you storing it in an array? Since you are storing it in an array I can only assume that you would be looping through the TB names and performing some action? If this is true then you do not need to store them in an array. You can directly loop though all the textboxes in a userform at runtime...

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you save a reference to your new textbox in `nieuwtxtingredient`.

You could save this reference in an array of Textbox and later read the name and value of each one.

This is how I suggest to revise your code :

```
Dim aantalBoxes As Integer
Dim ingredientArray() As Control

 Private Sub btnVoegToe_Click()

    Dim aantalRecepten As Integer
    Dim Teller As Integer

    aantalRecepten = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Cells(2, aantalRecepten + 2).Value = Me.txtNaamRecept.Value

    For Teller = 1 To aantalBoxes ' <-- starts at 1, formula below adjusted

        Cells(2 + Teller, aantalRecepten + 2).Value = ingredientArray(aantalBoxes).Value

    Next Teller

End Sub

Private Sub btnVolgendeIngredient_Click()

    aantalBoxes=aantalBoxes + 1     ' <-- must calculate the total

    ReDim Preserve ingredientArray(aantalBoxes) ' <-- you had this in the earlier version

    Set nieuwtxtingredient = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", "Ingredient", True)

    With nieuwtxtingredient

        .Width = Me.txtIngredient0.Width
        .Height = Me.txtIngredient0.Height
        .Left = Me.txtIngredient0.Left
        .Top = Me.txtIngredient0.Top + 30 * aantalBoxes
        .Name = "txtIngredient" + CStr(aantalBoxes)

    End With
                                       ' first Textbox is numbered 1
    set ingredientArray(aantalBoxes) = nieuwtxtingredient  ' <-- you had this in the earlier version

End Sub
```

Comment: I did that but When I change'ingredientArray() As String'  to 'ingredientArray() As textbox' and 'me.txtIngredient0.Value' to nieuwtxtingredient', I get a message :  Error 91 Object variable not set

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain clearly. I meant `Set ingredientArray(aantalBoxes) = nieuwtxtingredient` and to extract the value later use `=ingredientArray(i).Value`

Comment: I tried this, but now I get the message: Error 13 Type mismatch. I think there's something wrong with nieuwtxtingredient. It seems VBA doesn't recognise nieuwtxtingredient as a Textbox.

Comment: If at this point int the immediate window of the VB editor you type `? TypeName(nieuwtxtingredient)` what does it show ? Dim the array as the same type.

Comment: Sorry, you have to Dim the array as Control.

Comment: Allright, I don't get any error. But how do I extract the value? .Value doesn't exist for a Control

Comment: Value isn't listed as a property of control in the editor, but it's a property of the Textbox object (derived class of Control) that you've stored in the array. It works for me!

Comment: Ok, I understand. When I use this peace of code to put the text from the textboxes in my excelsheet 
`For Teller = 0 To aantalBoxes - 1`

`Cells(3 + Teller, aantalRecepten + 2).Value = ingredientArray(aantalBoxes).Value`

`Next Teller`

I get the error : error 9 subscript out of range

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ingredientArray(Teller+1).Value` ? I haven't enough of your code to see if you start at ingredientArray(1) or (0).

Comment: See my replay in the second answer.

Comment: Edited twice. Forgot Preserve!

Answer (score 0):

See this example, http://jsfiddle.net/7zkzttpr/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

When ever you create a new textbox, give the same name to the textbox as an array so that you can get the values of all textboxes in an array.